# Efficient way to dynamically rename a matrix in R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to dynamically add values to a matrix.
The code structure looks like:

```
for(f in length(file)) # loop through all files, which is 42 files in total
for(angle in c(0,45,90,135){
    for(dis in c(1,3,5){
         textureFeature2[f,(21*count - 20):(21*count)] <- as.matrix(calc_features(hbGLCM))
    }
}
```

The matrix will be filled after 12 loops. During each loop, I also want to rename the new columns once new values have been assigned to the 'textureFeature2' matrix. The value return by the calc_features is a dataframe and has colnames, but this information is lost once converted to matrix and assigned to the textureFeature2 matrix. My way to do this is quite dummy:

```
names(textureFeature2)[names(textureFeature2)      # Rename two variable names
                           %in% c(paste('V',count,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+1,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+2,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+3,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+4,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+5,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+6,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+7,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+8,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+9,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+10,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+11,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+12,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+13,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+14,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+15,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+16,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+17,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+18,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+19,sep = ''),
                                  paste('V',count+20,sep = '')
                                  )] <-
          c(paste(featureAffix, '_mean_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_variance_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_autoCorrelation_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_cProminence_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_cShade_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_cTendency_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_contrast_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_correlation_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_differentEntropy_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_dissimilarity_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_energy_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_entroypy_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_homogeneity1_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_homogeneity2_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_IDMN_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_IDN_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_inverseVariance_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_maxProb_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_sumAverage_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_sumEntropy_',angle,'_',d,sep = ''),
            paste(featureAffix, '_sumVariance_',angle,'_',d,sep = '')
          )
      }
    }
```

But this doesn't work as new columns are not renamed. Is there any smart way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As `paste` is vectorized, we can change the multiple `paste` calls to a single one

```
paste('V', count + 0:20)
```